# Get ps aux start time with seconds

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ps

I need the `ps aux` command to show the START time with seconds. Not just hour and the minute

I know there exists `lstart` but I don't know how to use it with `ps aux`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the command

```
ps -eo user,%mem,%cpu,start
```